# Unable to uninstall google chrome from windows 10 enterprise

Tags: uninstallation

I am unable to uninstall google chrome from my laptop. I have googled a lot  when I try bleow - 
On your computer, close all Chrome windows and tabs.
Click the Start menu Settings.
Click System.
On the left, click Apps & features.
**Find and click Google Chrome**.
to my surprise I never found Google chrome Icon even after killing chrome instance from taskmanager. If anyone has come across this please suggest to resolve the same.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for _programming_ questions and so this question is off-topic. However I think your first port of call is your IT support since there may be details about your laptop that are specific to your organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Uninstall a program and uninstall from there.